# Where can I find laptops on the Ubuntu "certified hardware" list for sale with Ubuntu pre-installed?

Tags: dell, laptop, lenovo

I'm in the market for a new laptop. In that past, I've purchased Windows laptops and wiped and installed Ubuntu myself. I recently discovered this list of laptops with "certified hardware" for Ubuntu 16.04:

https://certification.ubuntu.com/desktop/models/?release=16.04%20LTS&category=Laptop

All these listings state "Pre-installed by manufacturer". I would like to buy a laptop from this list. But when I go to the websites for Dell or Lenovo, I can't find the laptops I'm interested in available with Ubuntu as the OS.

Dell does list [Ubuntu laptops](http://pilot.search.dell.com/ubuntu%20laptop) but I'm looking for a laptop in the $600-800 range and these are all well above that.

Any idea where I can find laptops from this list with Ubuntu pre-installed?

Comment: I do not think that this is a good place to ask such a question. Anyway it depends on where you live. E.g. http://www.msystems.gr/index.php?stock=&keywords=&vendor=&category=1138&orderby=product_price&orderway=asc&filter7[]=_Linux_ sells Ubuntu preinstalled dell laptops in Greece.  https://www.entroware.com/store/ or https://system76.com/ would be good alternatives.